# Extension to a Complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the sequence $\left\{\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right);\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Is it possible to construct a complex  function such that the points of the sequence above are the only singularities?

Comment: I think you're going to have to add more stuff if you don't want people to downvote and close this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "a complex function", specifically? Like, are there restrictions on the domain?

Comment: A function on $\mathbb{C}$ where the singularities coincide with the points of the sequence.

Comment: If it is possible, the origin will be a non-isolated singularity. That what I'm trying to do. Given a sequence on the plane, I'm looking for a complex function whith the points of this sequence as the only singularities points.

Comment: I'm asking just if this is possible. I'm not an exper on Complex Analysis and I' don't know if is the question is plausible.

Comment: If the only singularities aer at those points then the origin cannot be a singularity which means it shuld be analytic in some neighborhood of the origin (a contradiction).